# Mongodb processing nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

Is there a nice solution/workaround to process nested arrays? I mean the only solution that came to my mind is a little bit ugly..it is a 2 phase flow: 1: find the id of the nested record in the array 2: build the query like

```
db.foo.update(
   {_id:"abc", "a.w":"some_other_value"}, 
   {$set:{"a.$.b.0.c":"new_value"}}
)
```

it should be easier to understand with schema example

```
doc:{
  _id:"abc",
  q:"some_value",
  a:[
    {
        w:"some_other_value",
        b:[
            {    
               k:1,
               c:"old_value"
             }
           ]
      }
   ]

}
```

Currently i am using scala+casbah if it is important.

Comment: please define what you mean by "processing" - if you mean "querying" or "updating".  For updating what you posted is exactly the right way to do it.

Comment: I mean "updating".. is this the only way we can do an update at the moment?

Comment: how else would you specify which element you want to update?

Comment: i could not find another way. but it looks ugly do to such things in 2 requests. may be the better solution at the moment is to use "stored procedure", i mean server side js.

Comment: It's not two requests - it's a single update...

Comment: How to find item index in array and update it item nested array element in one update?

Comment: I see what you are saying - you want to dynamically determine both indexes within the single update statement?  You currently cannot do that.  Watch and Vote https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831